# Stop for loop with a function inside in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, use-effect

i have this use effect that every time stopBet is true it runs the script, basically it gets the total amount of times that the process must be done and it does correctly, but i want to be able to stop it in any moment with a button, but i dont know how to handle it

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(stopBet) {
    if(numberBets > 0){
      for (let i=0; i<numberBets; i++) {
        task(i);
     } 
     function task(i) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           console.log(i, 'bet');
           const stopAt = numberBets-1;
           console.log(stopAt);
       if (i === stopAt){
             Submit()
             setLoading(false)
           }else{
            try {
              Submit()
             } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
             }
           } 
       }, 2000 * i);
     };
    } else {
       for (let i=0; i<99999; i++) {
        task(i);    
     };
     function task(i) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           console.log(i, 'bet');
            try {
              Submit()
             } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
             }
       }, 2000 * i);
     };
    };
  }
}, [stopBet]);
```

maybe there is a better way of doing this without a for loop but i havent figure it out, im still a newbie in react, so any advice would be appreciated

****Update****
So i did this code using the set interval property

```
   useEffect(() => {
  console.log(stopBet);
  let interval = null;
  if(stopBet){
    interval = setInterval(()=>{
      for (let i=0; i<numberBets; i++) {
        if(i === numberBets){
          setStopBet(false)
        }else{
          Submit()
        }
    } 
  },3000)
  }else{
    clearInterval(interval)
  }

  return () => clearInterval(interval)

}, [stopBet]);
```

but now the issue is that passed the 3 seconds this makes the submit function the times that i inserted throught the input, i dont know if my implementation of the for loop is the indicated for this

Comment: Why don't you try a setInterval of maybe 100ms instead of the loop? Then inside the setInterval check if the button is clicked or not before executing your logic. Because when you have an infinite loop like the one you have, it will make your web page unresponsive until the script has finished executing.

Comment: Building on H. Udara, setInterval returns an interval ID which you can stop by passing into clearInterval(). On button click, you can have it clear the intervalID that you save in your state.

Comment: Well i didnt know about the setInterval property, im going to make a research about how to use it and change the logic in base of this property, and then look about how to insert the amount of times that i want to be the process be maded, thanks for the info!

Comment: Create a button class with onClick={()=> this.setState({ value: false}) } and read button state to decide what to do

Comment: Yes i have that button, but the thing is when the submit in the for loop its done it triggers the api call the amount of times of the valor of numberBets, and i need to be able to stop the secuence of the api calls when i click that button